# How to force JSON-lib's JSONObject.put(..) to escape a string containing JSON?

Tags: java, json, serialization, json-lib

**When using JSON-lib's `JSONObject`, how can I stop the `put` method from storing a String which contains JSON as JSON rather than as an escaped string?**

For instance:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("jsonStringValue","{\"hello\":\"world\"}");
obj.put("naturalStringValue", "\"hello world\"");
System.out.println(obj.toString());
System.out.println(obj.getString("jsonStringValue"));
System.out.println(obj.getString("naturalStringValue"));
```

prints:

```
{"jsonStringValue":{"hello":"world"},"naturalStringValue":"\"hello world\""}
{"hello":"world"}
"hello world"
```

and I want it to print:

```
{"jsonStringValue":"{\"hello\":\"world\"}","naturalStringValue":"\"hello world\""}
{"hello":"world"}
"hello world"
```

Yes, I realize this is obnoxious.  However, this is in support of a JSON serialization pipeline for which, for interoperability's sake, this is the expected behavior.  There are cases in which we would be serializing user input which may be/contain valid JSON.  We wouldn't want the user input to become a part of the JSON object that we're serializing said input to.

Manual escaping doesn't work because it causes JSON-lib to escape the `\` characters:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("naturalJSONValue","{\"hello\":\"world\"}");
obj.put("escapedJSONValue", "{\\\"hello\\\":\\\"world\\\"}");
System.out.println(obj.toString());
System.out.println(obj.getString("naturalJSONValue"));
System.out.println(obj.getString("escapedJSONValue"));
```

Output:

```
{"naturalJSONValue":{"hello":"world"},"escapedJSONValue":"{\\\"hello\\\":\\\"world\\\"}"}
{"hello":"world"}
{\"hello\":\"world\"}
```

At this point, any workarounds to enable manual selective escaping of a complex JSON object would completely negate the value of using JSON-lib in the first place.

Also, I understand that this question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547143/json-lib-escaping-preserving-strings), but unfortunately I cannot accept its answer so easily.  JSON-lib is a heavily-used dependency in many areas of my project and swapping it out would be a big undertaking.  I need to be absolutely sure that there's no way to achieve this goal with JSON-lib before I can entertain a swap to Jackson, simple-json, or Gson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes to quote the string. From the [documentation](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/index.html):

> Strings may be quoted with ' (single quote).
>
> Strings do not need to be quoted at all if they do not begin with a quote or single quote, and if they do not contain leading or trailing spaces, and if they do not contain any of these characters: { } [ ] / \ : , = ; # and if they do not look like numbers and if they are not the reserved words true, false, or null.

So modifying your example:

```
net.sf.json.JSONObject obj = new net.sf.json.JSONObject();
obj.put("jsonStringValue","{\"hello\":\"world\"}");
obj.put("quotedJsonStringValue","\'{\"hello\":\"world\"}\'");
obj.put("naturalStringValue", "\"hello world\"");
System.out.println(obj.toString());
System.out.println(obj.getString("jsonStringValue"));
System.out.println(obj.getString("quotedJsonStringValue"));
System.out.println(obj.getString("naturalStringValue"));
```

Produces:

```
{"jsonStringValue":{"hello":"world"},"quotedJsonStringValue":"{\"hello\":\"world\"}","naturalStringValue":"\"hello world\""}
{"hello":"world"}
{"hello":"world"}
"hello world"
```

Note how `quotedJsonStringValue` has been treated as a string value and not JSON, and appears quoted in the output JSON.

Comment: As far as I understood the op the field-content is created by users and may contain anything including quotes of any kind and / or json. Would that work with your example, too?

Comment: @marsbear, if the data could include single-quotes, then yup, they would need to be escaped or stripped. Using `object().key().value()` would definitely be easier, I just chimed in because @Ben seemed to need to a workaround with just `JSONObject`.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me with json-lib 2.4:

```
System.out.println(
    new JSONStringer()
        .object()
            .key("jsonStringValue")
                .value("{\"hello\":\"world\"}")
            .key("naturalStringValue")
                .value("\"hello world\"")
        .endObject()
    .toString());
```

The output is:

```
{"jsonStringValue":"{\"hello\":\"world\"}","naturalStringValue":"\"hello world\""}
```

Comment: I would consider it, but per the interoperability requirement this serialization pipeline must be compatible with an existing system for which this is a somewhat common use case.

Comment: It is a specific existing legacy system with which this one must interface.  The system transports untrusted JSON as a properly escaped string rather than as part of the object itself.  I need to replicate this behavior.

Comment: Well then what about my previous suggestion but applied directly after json-encoding your stuff? Means: Pre-escape the special fields, json-lib encode everything and finally post-deescape those special fields. But that's quite an effort tho not that hard to achieve with regex.

Comment: Per the question "At this point, any workarounds to enable manual selective escaping of a complex JSON object would completely negate the value of using JSON-lib in the first place." -- especially if said manual escaping takes place post object serialization.  I'd rather deal with swapping out the library at that point.

Comment: Also, it's not that easy to achieve with regex.  For security's sake this needs to be a guaranteed solution that doesn't fall susceptible to weird edge cases, and this type of escaping must only be performed on a specific field in the JSON object.

Comment: I thought so but you said that replacing json-lib is very hard too as your environment depends on it. I'm sorry but I am out of crazy ideas :/ Well one last one: Have you thought about patching json-lib?

Comment: I'd be happy to write a patch to JSON-lib and submit it, but if it isn't accepted I don't want to maintain it myself.  Swapping it out will be a pain, but it's the right thing to do over hack-like workarounds or maintaining my own patch to it.

Comment: I do appreciate your effort, though.  I think this is just an intractable problem.

Comment: Found a solution. I am still looking for a way to achieve the same result with JSONObject, hang tight :)

Comment: Found no easy way tih JSONObject so far but JsonBuilder and JsonStringer seem to work fine. I modified my answer