# Deserialize string value by JSON-lib (net.sf.json)

Tags: json, deserialization, json-lib

I have discovered problem in [JSON-Lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) with deserialization of JSON string data in nested objects. Following code in Groovy demonstrates problem, you can test it in Groovy Console:

```
@Grab('net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.3:jdk15')
import net.sf.json.*

def s = '''\
{
  "attributes": "'{test:1}'",
  "nested": { "attributes": "'{test:1}'" }
}'''

def j = JSONSerializer.toJSON(s)

println j
assert j.attributes == "{test:1}" // OK
assert j.nested.attributes == "{test:1}" // Failed
```

In the example above both `attributes` in JSON have the same string value `"{test:1}"`. JSONSerializer deserialize the first one into `String` value but second one into (maybe)  `JSONObject`. I'm not sure because class of that object returns null.

For different string value (which doesn't look like JSON data, e.g. `"blah"`) it works.

How can I change this behavior?

**UPDATE**

I have tried to quote string values based on JSON-Lib documentation [here](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) (thanks to @GemK for pointing there), but with same result. Quoting string values doesn't work in nested objects :-(

Comment: This might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155560/how-to-force-json-libs-jsonobject-put-to-escape-a-string-containing-json

Comment: Thanks @GemK, but quote string values didn't solve the problem in nested objects.