# Sanitising a JSON String value in Java

Tags: java, json, escaping, sanitization, org.json

I need to accept a string from the user and put it as-is into a JSONObject. 
The [documentation](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) says strings may be quoted with `'` but it seems obvious I've misunderstood.

Is this sufficient or am I missing something?

```
jsonObject.put("name", "'" + userInput + "'");
```

I stepped through the `put` function but it doesn't seem to care about the string at all! There's a `quote` function but it adds another set of double quotes around the string which seems incorrect.

Comment: Why do you wrap your `userInput` in  `'`?

Comment: The json.org documentation says strings need to be quoted with `'`.

Comment: Please reference and quote that documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be quoting this part of the [Javadoc](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)

> Strings may be quoted with ' (single quote).

which is preceded by

> The texts produced by the `toString` methods strictly conform to the
>   JSON syntax rules. **The constructors are more forgiving in the texts
>   they will accept**:

[JSON strings are wrapped in double quotes `"`](http://json.org/). so `JSONObject#toString` will produce a JSON value where JSON strings will be syntactically correct. However, the `JSONObject` constructor can accept a JSON value (as text) where JSON strings are surrounded with single quotes instead of double quotes.

For example

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject("{'bad':'json'}"); // not valid JSON
System.out.println(object);
```

produces the valid

```
{"bad":"json"}
```

The `put` method is completely unrelated here. You don't need (and shouldn't) use single quotes around your specified string.

---

From your comments

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("jsonStringValue","{\"hello\":\"world\"}");
obj.put("naturalStringValue", "\"hello world\"");
System.out.println(obj.toString());
System.out.println(obj.getString("jsonStringValue"));
System.out.println(obj.getString("naturalStringValue"));
```

prints

```
{"jsonStringValue":"{\"hello\":\"world\"}","naturalStringValue":"\"hello world\""}
{"hello":"world"}
"hello world"
```

Comment: But according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155560/how-to-force-json-libs-jsonobject-put-to-escape-a-string-containing-json if the string is valid JSON the `put` function embeds it as a nested JSON object! The answer there says to wrap it in single quotes.

Comment: @Locutus What are you trying to do? `JSONObject#put` takes the second argument and converts it to an appropriate JSON value. If it's a String, it will convert it to a JSON string (escaping characters that need it). It it's a number, it will convert it to a JSON number. If it's an array, a JSON array. If it's an object, a JSON object. If you're trying to insert JSON into JSON, create a `JSONObject` from the `userInput` and `put` that.

Comment: @Locutus Obviously, if you don't know if the `userInput` is a JSON value, then `JSONObject` correctly does provide a way to write it to the JSON text raw. If the `userInput` was not valid JSON, it would break the final JSON value.

Comment: I want to treat it purely as a string. But in that question, even when providing `put` with a string (and not a JSONObject), it's turning the string into a nested JSONObject if the string happens to be valid JSON! Look at his example code, specifically the `jsonStringValue` part.

Comment: @Locutus They must either be using an old (buggy) version of the library or misrepresenting their results. If you `put` a Java `String` using `JSONObject#put`, the corresponding value of the JSON key-value pair will be a JSON String where all necessary characters will be escaped. For example, a double quote `"` must and will be escaped.